# How to pass an array through $.get?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var social_buttons_array = [];
social_buttons_array["google"] = $("input[name='social_popup_google']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
social_buttons_array["twitter"] = $("input[name='social_popup_twitter']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
social_buttons_array["twitter_follow"] = $("input[name='social_popup_twitter_follow']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
social_buttons_array["facebook"] = $("input[name='social_popup_facebook']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
```

And I am trying to pass the array like this:

```
$.get(
    ajaxurl,
    {
        action: 'process_data',
        get: 'social_popup',
        social_buttons_array : social_buttons_array // not works
    },
    function(response) {
    },
    'json'
    );
```

This do not works. Any idea to pass the array?

---

**EDIT && solution**

I edit this question to replace the `associative array` by an object that will act as an array.

```
var social_buttons_array = new Object();
social_buttons_array.google = $("input[name='social_popup_google']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
social_buttons_array.twitter = $("input[name='social_popup_twitter']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
social_buttons_array.twitter_follow = $("input[name='social_popup_twitter_follow']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
social_buttons_array.facebook = $("input[name='social_popup_facebook']").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;

$.get(
    ajaxurl,
    {
        action: 'process_data',
        get: 'social_popup',
        social_buttons_array : JSON.stringify(social_buttons_array) // it works great over an object
    },
    function(response) {
    },
    'json'
    );
```

To manage this array/object in php we need:

```
$social_buttons_array = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['social_buttons_array']));
```

And then we must manage this var as an object:

```
echo $social_buttons_array->google
// results in 1 or 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize it with [JSON.stringify()](http://www.json.org/js.html)?

```
social_buttons_array : JSON.stringify(social_buttons_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

A GET request places your values in the URL in the form:

```
page.php?arg1=value&arg2=value2
```

So you cannot just pass an associative array unless you somehow convert it to a string value (maybe in Json format, as antisanity suggested).

Another option may be to pass each key of the dictionary as a URL parameter.

```
var urlParams  = {
    action: 'process_data',
    get: 'social_popup',
};

for (key in social_buttons_array) {
    urlParams[key] = social_buttons_array[key];
}

$.get(ajaxurl, urlParams, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Which will send something like this:

```
page.php?action=process_data&get=social_popup&google=0&twitter=0&twitter_follow=0&facebook=0
```

It really depends how you are going to process that data on the server side.

Comment: +1 thanks, it's a good and valuable solution. But I want pass an array-like data.